# Best way to cache in Google App Engine Node

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, redis, google-cloud-platform

In the google App Engine docs for Node.js it only recommends [redis](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-redislabs-memcache), for other languages it has native memcache. Is there a better caching system than making exterior calls to redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far native memcache is only available to standard environment apps. But it's true, native memcache future availability on flex env was announced at least for python and java. From [Memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#memcache):

> The Memcache service is currently not available for the App Engine
>   flexible environment. An alpha version of the memcache service will be
>   available shortly. If you would like to be notified when the service
>   is available, fill out this [early access form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfGMYNeKC0G5aw6GEiocL1DjT2H5AFUCqsbxoerfuj3Y1rHxw/viewform?c=0&w=1).

Please note that the Redis service comes in 2 flavours:

- [redis](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-redislabs-redis)
- [memcached](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-redislabs-memcache)

Both of these services can be provided right from inside google datacenters, in which case they don't exactly make *outside calls*. From [Setting up](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-redislabs-memcache#setting_up) (on either service):

> 2. ... Be sure to specify `GCE/us-central1` as the Cloud for the lowest latency

This means they *shouldn't* differ too much in performance compared to the native memcache, which is also offered on some (other) servers in the google datacenters. Well, at least for GAE apps hosted in `us-central1`.

**Note:** this is all based on docs, I didn't yet use the flex environment.

Comment: Ok so I can use either one, but I should pick the data center where my data is located? Thank you

Comment: If you see a `GCE/` one closer, yes. If not I'd measure and compare the closest one outside GCE vs `GCE/us-central1` - Google's network is likely faster that the public one, access to `GCE/us-central1` might be faster even if it's not closer.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dan says Memcache is not available (yet) for Node.js
If you need to cache Datastore entities, there is a library ([nsql-cache-datastore](https://github.com/sebelga/nsql-cache-datastore)) that has a *memory* cache and can connect to a *Redis* db. Its "memory" cache store is only useful if you have **one** App engine instance.